# Action(Of T) in Visual Basic in List(Of T).ForEach

Tags: vb.net, generics, foreach

I have searched high and low for documentation on how to use this feature. While the loop I *could* write would be simple and take no time, I really would like to learn how to use this.

Basically I have a class, say, `Widget`, with a `Save()` sub that returns nothing. So:

```
Dim w as New Widget()
w.Save()
```

basically saves the widget. Now let's say I have a generic collection `List(Of Widget)` name `widgetList(Of Widget)` and I want to run a `Save()` on each item in that list. It says I can do a

```
widgetList.ForEach([enter Action(Of T) here])
```

....but how in the F does this work??? There is no documentation anywhere on the intrablags. Help would be much much appreciated.

Comment: ps i did some research on lambda functions and tried some of those techniques, but i couldn't get any of them to work... ugh...

Comment: If you are using Visual Studio 2005 you won't have access to Lamda expressions in VB

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you're using VB9 (VS2008) I don't *think* you'll be able to use an anonymous function easily - as far as I'm aware, anonymous functions in VB9 *have* to be real functions (i.e. they have to return a value) whereas `Action<T>` doesn't return anything. C# 2's anonymous methods and C# 3's lambda expressions are more general, which is why you'll see loads of examples using `List<T>.ForEach` from C# and very few using VB :(

You could potentially write a `MakeAction` wrapper which *takes* a `Function<T,TResult>` and returns an `Action<T>`, but I suspect other restrictions on VB9 anonymous functions would make this impractical.

The good news is that [VB10 has much more anonymous function support](http://www.thinqlinq.com/default/Delegates-and-Lambdas-in-VB-10.aspx). (C#4 and VB10 are gaining each other's features - I believe MS is trying to go for language parity from now on, to a larger extent than before.)

Until then, to use `List<T>.ForEach` you'll need to write an appropriate `Sub` and use `AddressOf` to create a delegate from it. Here's a small example:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Class Test

    Shared Sub Main()
        Dim names as New List(Of String)
        names.Add("Jon")
        names.Add("Holly")
        names.ForEach(AddressOf PrintMe)

    End Sub

    Shared Sub PrintMe(ByVal text as String)
        Console.WriteLine(text)
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: thank you, and thank you for the example! I wish there were a better way than cluttering up my already-growing list of class functions, but this works for now!

Comment: It's not really that practical.. is it?

Answer (score 17):

well, I'm really outdated now... :-) but in VB it's:

```
widgetList.ForEach(Sub(w) w.Save())
```

or, more complicated:

```
widgetList.ForEach(New Action(Of Widged)(Sub(w As Widged) w.Save()))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
new Action(Of T)(AddressOf Widget.Save)
```

is OK if Widget got a public function called `Save`.

All others comment are false when I try it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that VB does not support lambda expressions, you can create an instance of the Action(of T) delegate in VB using this syntax:

```
new Action(Of T)(AddressOf Widget.Save)
```

Answer (score -2):

The below should work although I'm not up to speed on VB.Net so you may need to adjust accordingly.

```
widgetList.ForEach(w => w.Save())
```

Comment: that's the problem... C# and VB differ a lot on this, so i need the VB syntax.....