# NHibernate SchemaUpdate recreate DB, but not update

Tags: c#, nhibernate, schema, database-migration

I implemented DB migration, and stuck. I use this code to check SchemaUpdate's script:

```
List<string> scripts = new List<string>(1000);
_cfg.BuildMappings();

SchemaUpdate schemaUpdate = new SchemaUpdate(_cfg);
schemaUpdate.Execute(str =>
{
   scripts.Add(str);
}, true);
```

My DB contains several tables. I added new Test table. I expected that script will contain only one item for table create. But I was surprised, that he create all tables.

How to fix this issue?

**Update**

SchemaUpdate throws exceptions for all items except Test table.

```
There is already an object named XXX
```

Comment: which database driver do you use? is the connection string correct?

Comment: @Firo driver=NHibernate.Driver.SqlClientDriver and connection string is fine. connection string = Server=(local);Database=MyDataBase;user=admin;password=pass;

Comment: Probably DUP of http://stackoverflow.com/a/6799401/1036187

Comment: use `new MsSqlDataBaseSchema(session.Connection).GetTables(catalog, schemaPattern, new [] {"TABLE", "VIEW"})` to see which tables schemaupdate sees#

Comment: @Firo there are no tables in DB=(. I also tried ValidateSchema in Configuration class and it says that tables are missing. Do you know how to deal with this?

Comment: are you really use MsSqlServer and does `connection.GetSchema();` return something? (connection is a manually created Connection from the ADO.NET-driver you use)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finded solution. It is my mistake. I named all tables like [Table]. NHibernate compares [Table] and Table. That's why it tries to create them. Thanks Firo for advice)